# What is the proper way to set an instance variable using a function call

Tags: python

What is the best practice when using a setter method which only calls out to an external method. I don't want the user to change this value.
I have the following structure

```
class Instruction(object):
    def __init__(self, address):
        super(Instruction, self).__init__()
        self.address = address
        self.mnem = self.__set_mnem()

    @property
    def mnem(self):
        return self.__mnem

    def __set_mnem(self):
        return extModule.GetMnem(self.address)
```

Should I instead have this

```
    @mnem.setter
    def mnem(self, mnem=None):
        if not mnem:
            self.__mnem = extModule.GetMnem(self.address)
        else:
            self.__mnem = None
```

Comment: whoops, just changed it. I have a few methods similar to this and I copied over the wrong if statement haha

Comment: If you don't want the user to change the value of `self.mnem`, one approach is to simply document that fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your property should be read-only, you simply do not give it a setter, no. Set the private attribute that the property accesses:

```
class Instruction(object):
    def __init__(self, address):
        super(Instruction, self).__init__()
        self.address = address
        self.__mnem = extModule.GetMnem(self.address)

    @property
    def mnem(self):
        return self.__mnem
```

Now `Instruction().mnem` is read-only, and the value for it is set when you create the instance.

Comment: I see. So set the variable itself private and set it using the method, then just use the property to access it. That makes perfect sense. Thanks